# Wordpress order posts by post type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am trying to create a system which fetches post from 2 post types and i want to display the posts order by their post type. I am trying to first show the posts from one post type and then another post type but the query i used mixes it all. Can any one suggest a good solution for this. Here is my code.

```
    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
 $args = array(

     'post_type' => array('review','directory'),
     'orderby' => 'name',
     'order' => 'ASC',
     'posts_per_page'  => '4',
     'paged'          => $paged ,
     'tax_query' => array( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'Reviews',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $cat_id
    ), ),
     );

 query_posts($args);
        if (have_posts()) :
       while (have_posts()) : the_post();
      $product_terms = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), 'Reviews', array("fields" => "all", "order" => "DESC"));
      $postype=get_post_type( get_the_ID() );
      if($postype=='review')
      {
     ?>   

        <div class="review-post">
          <a href="http://<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
          <div class="review-cat-new">
            <?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'Reviews', 'Category: ', ', ', '' ); ?>
          </div>

          <?php
          if(get_field('see_it'))
              $seeit_text= get_field('see_it');
         if(get_field('skip_it'))
              $skipit_text= get_field('skip_it');
         ?>
          <div class="see-skip">
            <p class="see-it"><span>See it:</span>
                <?php echo $seeit_text; ?>
            </p>
            <p class="skip-it"><span>Skip it:</span>
                <?php echo $skipit_text;  ?>
            </p>
          </div>
          <?php echo custom_field_excerpt(); ?>
        </div>
          <?php }
          else
          {
              ?>
                <div class="review-post">
          <a href="h<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
          <div class="review-cat-new">
            <?php echo get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'Reviews', 'Category: ', ', ', '' ); ?>
          </div>


          <?php echo the_field('enter_content_direc'); ?>
          <?php
          if(get_field('enter_textdirec'))
              $text= get_field('enter_textdirec');
         if(get_field('enter_linkdirec'))
              $textlink= get_field('enter_linkdirec');
         ?>
          <div class="see-skip">
            <p class="see-it direc"><span><a  target="_blank" style="color:#5D6D71; text-transform: lowercase;" href="<?php echo $textlink;?>"><?php echo $textlink;?>  </a></span>

            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
          <?php }
          endwhile;
                  echo '<div class="paging">';
                 wp_pagenavi();
                 echo '</div>';
                endif;
```

So is there a way so that i can first show the posts form reviews and then directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i got the solution and it can be done using a filter.

The solution looks like this.

```
add_filter( 'posts_request' , 'modify_request' );
function modify_request( $query) {
    global $wpdb;
    if(strstr($query,"post_type IN ('review', 'directory')")){
        $where = str_replace("ORDER BY {$wpdb->posts}.post_date","ORDER BY {$wpdb->posts}.post_type",$query);
    }
    return $where;
}
```

Comment: where do you put this code? I get an error if I try and put it in archive-name.php

Comment: put it on functions.php

Comment: More info. If you want to change "order by" only,  wordpress has `posts_orderby_request` filter.

Comment: Hi @NirmalRam, there seems to be something wrong here ... $query is not returned when the if condition isn't met, effectively producing no results. Also, should the $where be implemented that way. Is it not maybe a property of the $query object?

Answer (score 5):

As seen in the docs https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters , you can use the regular wp query by passing an array to 'orderby' :

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query(
  array(
      's' => $search,
      'orderby'=> array('type'=>'DESC', 'title'=>'ASC'),
      'paged'=>$paged
  )
);
if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {
        $wp_query->the_post();
        // do your loop stufff here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since Wordpress 4.0 you can just pass the option type (post_type) to the orderby parameter in the WP_Query object.

**orderby (string | array) - Sort retrieved posts by parameter. To order by post type just pass:**

- 'type' - Order by post type (available since Version 4.0). ('post_type' is also accepted.)

Comment: Is it possible to get the post_types in a specific order? for example: the order off the array.

Comment: The developer docs don't mention this, but it is true and here is the code: https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/5.8.1/src/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L1574

Answer (score 2):

Order per post types with custom post type order:

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', function ($query) {

    if ($query->is_search && !is_admin()) :
        $query->set('post_type', [ 'cpt-1', 'cpt-2', 'post', 'cpt-3']);
    endif;

    return $query;
});



add_filter('posts_orderby', function ( $order ) {

    if ( ! is_admin() ) :

        if ( is_search() && is_main_query() ) :

            global $wpdb;
            $order = "FIELD( post_type, 'cpt-1', 'cpt-2', 'post' ), {$wpdb->posts}.post_modified DESC";      
        endif;

    // Disable this filter for future queries!
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__);
    endif;

    return $order;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First solution which comes to my mind is to get posts only for first category. Reset query (`wp_reset_query()`) and get them again for second category. You need to double up your code of course, but I don't see any other solution - it's WordPress - you're very limited.

Second solution is to query database directly like this:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * 
FROM  `wp_posts` 
WHERE post_type =  "page"
OR post_type =  "post"
ORDER BY post_type ASC , post_date DESC ');

$posts = array();

if($result) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $posts[] = $row;
    }
}

mysql_free_result($result);

echo('<pre>');
var_dump($posts);
echo('</pre>');
die();
```

Notice that I've used `post` and `page` types as these are default, and exist in my WP installation. But you can use different. You can play with this query as much as you want.

Comment: Thanks but i don't want that, What i want is to sort the post by post_type

Comment: Then you will have to probably make your own quering php function reading directly from db. Is it an option for you?

Comment: No this is not right. I have figured it out and it works. Just a filter would do the job.