# Wordpress site - display list of custom posts alphabetically

Tags: wordpress

I have created a post type 'Artists' and I would like to edit the page site.com/Artists so it displays the Artist names in a grid alphabetically with pagination and shows links A, B, C, D.... allowing the user to search alphabetically for all Artist names beginning with that specific letter.

How do I do this? Which template file should I edit to edit the page site.com/Artists? I'm not sure where to put the query coding.

Answer (score 0):

This was answered in another question here **[Wordpress order posts by post type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675296/wordpress-order-posts-by-post-type).**

It looks like this person had the same issue as you (in concept). You just choose which element of the array to order by.