# Query Custom Post Types & Order By Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Is it possible to query multiple CPTs and then order in a preset way?

For example, I have 2 CPTs & 1 being the WP default 'post' and would like the loop to return 6 results, ordering as below.

- CPT-1
- CPT-2
- POST
- CPT-1
- CPT-2
- POST

Is this possible without splitting the loop?

I did have a quick search, but could only find one article relating to this, the solutions from which don't appear to work any more...

[Wordpress order posts by post type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675296/wordpress-order-posts-by-post-type)

Comment: So there should always be 2 items from each post type?

Comment: Yep, correct...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a shortened version of Sephsekla's code:

```
$my_post_types = array( 'CPT-1', 'CPT-2', 'post', 'CPT-1', 'CPT-2', 'post' );
$posts_shown = array();
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'CPT-1', 'CPT-2', 'post' ),
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);
$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
foreach ( $my_post_types as $post_type ):
    while ( $my_query->have_posts() ): $my_query->the_post();
        if ( $post_type == get_post_type() && ! in_array( get_the_ID(), $posts_shown ) ) {
            echo '<pre>' . get_post_type() .': '. get_the_title() . '</pre>';
            $posts_shown[] = get_the_id();
            break;
        }
    endwhile;
    $my_query->rewind_posts();
endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: That's significantly more elegant, and less clunky than my old code by a long way. Definitely go with this one.

Comment: How would you modify your code @vayu-robins to include a different template file for each post type?

Comment: @revive please have a look at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/. You can name your template parts differently by using get_post_typ()

Answer (score 1):

This is something I've done before a while ago, and while it is doable with just one query it's a bit of a long-winded setup.

The gist of it is that you can use one query, then loop through the query until you find the first post you're after. Then exit the loop and use `WP_Query->rewind_posts()` to put the query back to the start.

Then you can run a second loop with a different condition. And then a third.

For the fourth, fifth and sixth loops you also need to check that you're not repeating the first set.

See below for the code in all its glory.

```php
<?php

$my_query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    )
);

$post_1 = $post_2 = $post_3 = $post_4 = $post_5 = $post_6 = 0;

if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    /*First loop through posts*/
    while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        $my_query->the_post();
        /**
         * Find the first post
        */

        if ( 'CPT-1' == get_post_type() && $post_1 == 0 ) {
            do_something_with_the_post();
            $post_1 = get_the_id();
            break;
        }
    }

    $my_query->rewind_posts();

    /*Second loop through posts*/
    while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        $my_query->the_post();

        /**
         * Find the second post
        */
        if ( 'CPT-2' == get_post_type() && $post_2 == 0 ) {
            do_something_with_the_post();
            $post_2 = get_the_id();
            break;
        }
    }
    $my_query->rewind_posts();

    /*Third loop through posts*/
    while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        $my_query->the_post();

        /**
         * Find the third post
        */
        if ( 'post' == get_post_type() && $post_3 == 0 ) {
            do_something_with_the_post();
            $post_3 = get_the_id();
            break;
        }
    }

    $my_query->rewind_posts();

    /**
     * Then we repeat this process but also check we don't use the same post twice
     */

    /*Fourth loop through posts*/
    while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        $my_query->the_post();

        /**
         * Find the fourth post
        */
        if ( 'CPT-1' == get_post_type() && $post_4 == 0 && get_the_id() !== $post_1 ) {
            do_something_with_the_post();
            $post_1 = get_the_id();
            break;
        }
    }

    $my_query->rewind_posts();

    /*Fifth loop through posts*/
    while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        $my_query->the_post();

        /**
         * Find the fifth post
        */

        if ( 'CPT-2' == get_post_type() && $post_5 == 0 && get_the_id() !== $post_2 ) {
            do_something_with_the_post();
            $post_5 = get_the_id();
            break;
        }
    }

    $my_query->rewind_posts();

    /*Sixth loop through posts*/
    while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        $my_query->the_post();

        /**
         * Find the sixth post
        */
        if ( 'post' == get_post_type() && $post_6 == 0 && get_the_id() !== $post_3 ) {
            do_something_with_the_post();
            $post_6 = get_the_id();
            break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * And we're finished
     */
}
```

Comment: Have not there any solution without multiple time loop ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to accomplish something similar and although Vayu's [code is super elegant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55641412/225230), it doesn't accomplish what I need - specifically I need to be able to include a different template part for each post type (they have slightly different content) as well as add an $arg for the WP post (that is not a CPT) to target a specific category

What I'm trying to accomplish is this (just in logic format with $args above):

```
    $my_post_types = array( 'auctions', 'liquidations', 'inventory',  'post' );

    // set args for ALL posts
    $args = array(
        'post_type'     => $my_post_types,
        'orderby'       => 'date',
        'order'         => 'DESC',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
    );
    
    Now we loop through posts (while loop)

    IF 'post_type == auctions' 
        add number_posts to $args from ACF field for this post type
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/card', 'auction' );  

    IF 'post_type == liquidations' 
        add number_posts to $args from ACF field for this post type
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/card', 'liquidations' );  

    IF 'post_type == inventory' 
        add number_posts to $args from ACF field for this post type
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/card', 'inventory' );  

    IF 'post_type == post' 
        add 'cat => 304' to $args 
        add number_posts to $args from ACF field for this post type
        and get_template_part( 'template-parts/card', 'studies' );
```

The goal is to show all of the CPTs and Posts, in the qty set for each type in the admin, sorted by date, on one page. I need to update/add to the $args for each of the post type loops....